# Plotting a cumulative binomial distribution

Tags: plotting, distributions

The curve is correct, however I am not sure why it is not fully touching the x- and y-axes; it's just floating in the middle of the plot.

Here is my Mathematica code:

```
Plot[CDF[BinomialDistribution[75, p], 1], {p, 0.005, 0.04}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.00, 0.10}, {0.00, 1.00}}, AxesLabel -> {p, OC (p)}]
```

The first image below is what I am getting with my code. The second image is how I would like it to look.

[image: my picture]

[image: What it should be]

Comment: You constrained the plot to `{p, 0.005, 0.04}`.If you want the full plot use `{p, 0, 0.1}`

Comment: Your code plots a PDF not CDF. Do you really want a CDF?

Answer (score 1):

To get a plot that looks like the 2nd image you show in your question, you need to change your code to something like

```
Plot[CDF[BinomialDistribution[75, p], 1], {p, 0., 0.1},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  AxesLabel -> {"p", "OC (p)"}]
```

plot
[image]

Note that you don't have to specify the plot range, but you do need to enlarge the domain of the plot.